# I want Prometheus metrics in a file instead of prometheus UI

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

> I installed prometheus in kubernetes and its working fine.
> But actually i want all metrics in a file instead of Prometheus UI.
> please help me;

Comment: How do you imagine this? How is it supposed to work?

Comment: Query Prometheus API

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there is a cleaner way to do it but what you can try is query all jobs from prometheus server ui by port forwarding the server pod

Find all jobs (from your config file or query to find all jobs)

For each job query unique metric names
{**name**=~".+", job="prometheus"}

Expect frequent timeouts while querying if there are too many time series or too many metrics